# FTP only works when I use Thread.Sleep

Tags: c#, ftp

I have a small console app that scrapes some data and uploads it to an FTP directory using the FtpWebRequest object - very typical.

I had it working successfully while I was stepping through it with the debugger. Files were being written to the remote server with the correct data. Then when I took the breakpoints out and let it rip, it created the file with no data, then hung until it finally timed out. No exception other than the timeout was returned. I put the breakpoint back in and sure enough it worked perfectly.

I figured that the act of debugging was causing a pause and put in a Thread.Sleep(10), and, again, worked perfectly.

I'd be happy with just an explanation for this (as long as it's not terrible practice), but suggestions on how to do it better would also be appreciated. I'll note that I only sparingly use 3rd Party controls.

**EDIT:** I should also mention that I don't want to have to create a physical file, I'd rather just write the Stream directly.

Here's the relevant code:

```
        filePathAndName = new Uri(String.Format("{0}{1}_{2}.txt", Properties.Settings.Default.QTMFTPDirectory, 
            fileNamePrefix, DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyHHmmss")));
        fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(csv);

        request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(filePathAndName);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Properties.Settings.Default.FTPUserName, Properties.Settings.Default.FTPPassword);
        request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;
        request.KeepAlive = false;

        try
        {
            using (Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                reqStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10); // Won't work without this.
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogError(ex);
        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Not a solution, but all this code could be replaced with `WebCLient.UploadFile()`, sidestepping this issue.

Comment: A possible cause is that you might have duplicate filenames here. You would have trouble overwriting a file that is still finishing.

Comment: @Henk - Thanks for the input. I'll edit the post to add that I don't want to have to create the physical file before uploading. With `FtpWebRequest`, it can be a Stream, but `WebClient.UploadFile()` looks like it can only take a file name as a string. 

I don't think duplicate names is an issue. I'm timestamping with seconds and manually clearing out the directory each time.

Comment: Have you tried calling GetResponse to wait for the response from the server?

Comment: @LuizFelipe, yes, it hangs until timeout.

Comment: There is UploadData(). And seconds seems coarse. Anyway, make sure you _know_ it's not a problem. Thinking isn't good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try manually closing it.

```
reqStream.Close(); // Close
```

and if that does not help, you can try getting the response from the server.

```
GetResponse();
```

Source:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.getrequeststream(v=vs.110).aspx

Edit:

I know, the `using` keyword sometimes does not close a connection correctly.

Comment: Thanks @El Mac, I tried replacing the `using` statement with an explicit `Close()`, but that didn't fix the problem.